# javascript getting incorrect date time form share point 2013 calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image]

```
var liEnum = colListItem.getEnumerator();

    while(liEnum.moveNext())
    {
        var oLiCal=liEnum.get_current();                                   
        var eventStartDate = oLiCal.get_item('EventDate');  
        var eventEndDate = oLiCal.get_item('EndDate');  

        var eventStartDateLocaleString = eventStartDate.toLocaleString();
        var eventEndDateLocaleString = eventEndDate.toLocaleString();

        console.log("server start date is: " + eventStartDate); 
        console.log("local start date is: " + eventStartDateLocaleString);

        console.log("server start end date is: " + eventEndDate);
        console.log("local end date is: " + eventEndDateLocaleString);
```

The result I get is the following:

[image]

I am located at central time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend Moment.js. [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

It's a fantastic lightweight library I've used many times within a SP context, handy for those ISO formatted dates.

Usage:

var dateformat = "DD MMMM YYYY";
  var formattedDate = moment(eventStartDate).format(dateformat);